# Spark shuffle when double repartition

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, amazon-emr, shuffle

I am trying to join some datasets in Spark and I trying to do that without shuffle.

Unfortunately after running some test I saw something odd.

Let's say I have dataset A in S3 as plaintext (Json string).

First, I read the dataset A and repartition it by a specific field. This is a dummy code as example:

```scala
val rddA = sc.textFile(s3InputPath)
             .map(x => objectMapper.readValue(x, classOf[APojo]))
             .map(x => (x.getId(), x)) // "id" field is type of String
             .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(10))
             .map(x => objectMapper.writeValueAsString(x._2))

rddA.saveAsTextFile(s3OutputPath)
```

Then I try to read the previous dataset and run the exact same repartition:

```scala
val rddAClone = sc.textFile(s3OutputPath)
                  .map(x => objectMapper.readValue(x, classOf[APojo]))
                  .map(x => (x.getId(), x))
                  .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(10))
                  .map(x => objectMapper.writeValueAsString(x._2))

rddAClone.collect //any operation to force the spark to process the RDD
```

My expectation was that, because I priorly repartitioned my dataset by "id", when I try to repartition it again, the operation will finish without any shuffle. Unfortunately, I still see some shuffle in the Spark's Application Monitor (<5% of the input dataset as shuffle)

Do any of you have confronted with the same problem? Is this behaviour intended or is something wrong with my assumption/expectancy?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try caching the rdd with `rddA.cache()`. I think that might avoid a shuffle in the second code snippet

Comment: This is range partition which spark doesn't remember. A list partition might help avoid the shuffle.

Comment: I actually used `HashPartitioner` which basically uses the same hash function each time. I edited my question.